# RabbitMQ - How to override the replyTimeout for sendAndReceive?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I am configuring the amqp template using the spring amqp definition like

```
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" reply-timeout="45000" />
```

Now, while calling the `amqpTemplate.sendAndReceive("COR.QUEUE", message)`, can I change the replyTimeout for specific requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the timeout for individual send operations; it is a constant value.

If you only have a few different values you need, you can simply declare multiple templates, each with a different timeout.

You could also create a wrapper class that creates multiple templates on-demand, one for each requested timeout.

```
private final Map<Long, RabbitTemplate> templates = new HashMap<>();

public Message sendAndReceive(String rk, Message message, long timeout) {
    // lookup a template for the requested timeout, or add one to the map
    return lookedupTemplate.sendAndReceive(rk, message);
}
```